# Get data using Date and Time from sql in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple console application and this application gets data from the SQL server. I have to search data using date and time from the SQL server. This below code works if I enter only the year for example if I enter `2017` or `2018`, then it gets data of all that year but if I try to enter in `2017-07-22`, then it doesn't get any data. My SQL server has date format of `year-month-day hh-mm-ss`. I am kind of stuck here. Any suggestions?

```
using (var context = new Model1())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Date");
    DateTime dateTime;
    var s = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
    s = Console.ReadLine();

    var result = context.Databases.
        Where(x => x.RecordedTime.Value.ToString().
        Contains(s)).ToList(); ;

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.RecordedTime.Value.ToShortDateString()}, {item.Temperature}");
    }

}
```

Comment: The whole approach makes no sense.  You create a datetime (that has its default value), you convert it to a string and assign it to `s`, then you take userinput to completely override `s`.

Comment: What you should be doing is just take a user input, use `DateTime.TryParse()` to parse that string into a date, then use LINQ with actual dates and not string comparisons.

Comment: Agreed with @maccettura. There is no need to use strings. Parse the data from the user into a `Date` variable as indicated, then use that for comparison.

Comment: I tried using the TryParse too but it also return data if i enter only date but not with full date

Comment: See the answer on TryParseExact.  Also, for your own sanity, don't use methods inside brackets in your strings, just generate the string you want and then insert it with string concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert to string, you need to only parse it. To parse with an exact format you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` like this, based in the format you provided:

```
s = Console.ReadLine();

DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(s, 
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dt);

//... do linq stuff with variable dt
```

Comment: with this solution, it works perfectly with year but not when i enter full date. when i enter 2017-07-22, then it  doesnt show anything. but it shows when i enter only 2017.

Comment: @user3280146 - Look into the various parsing methods.  `TryParseExact` is one of them.  It has lots of options.  `ParseExact`, `Parse`, and `TryParse` are the other ones.  You'll have to make some decisions based on what you expect your user to do.

Comment: @Guilherme - careful that if you use `hh` that you also supply `tt`.  Alternatively use `HH`.  Otherwise there's no capability to provide times after noon.

Comment: @user3280146, this exemple I posted should work with the format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss` that you provided, have you tried something like `2017-11-01 09-10-10` as input?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I fixed the problem.